# Render and navigation Issue with iOS build in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, navigation

The view is not rendering in iOS build but its running fine in Android,
the view is not navigating to the next view.

Here is the navigation structure, the screen not navigating from Address Result to AddressDetail

```
const StackNav = StackNavigator({
Main: {
    screen: Addresssearch,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Address Search",
        header: null
    })
},
AddressDetail: {
    screen: AddressDetails,
    navigationOptions: (props) => ({
        title: "Profile View",
    })
},
AddressResult: {
    screen: AddressResult,
    navigationOptions: (props) => ({
        title: "",
    })
},{
   headerMode: 'float' 
 })
```

The render Function of Address Detail class

```
render(){
     console.log("=========== View Details Props ============");
    const {bgImageTop, boxWithName, phoneIcon, showMapBtn, locationIcon, profile_icon} = images;
    const { container, topCover, coverView, subContainer, info1, titleLabel, profileImage,subHeading } = styles;

    const {data, differentSearchData} = this.state.dataArray;
    const personData = data
    const { firstname, lastname, middlename, age, streetAddress, city, zipcode, landline } = personData["0"];
    const routeName = this.props.navigation.state.routeName
  console.log("routeName: "+routeName)
    const { onScroll = () => {} } = this.props;

    return(
        <View>
          <Text>Read</Text>
        </View>
    );
}}
```

Here the console statement is executed but I can't see the screen navigating from Address Result to Address Details in iOS build

Details:

```
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.48.3",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
```

Comment: Is AddressDetail showing in android?

Comment: yes it's showing in android but not in iOS